# dynamic dropdownlist in ASP.net Razor MVC5 from a Many to many database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown

Here is the look of my tables in MSSQL MS : 
[MSSQL Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N8xZ.png)
As i’ve learned, Entity Framework is changing the schema to hide the middle database and made it look like this : 
[VB view with Entity Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmWcI.png)

I dont really know how to use the middle table (and if i should use it or not).

The idea of my website is to be able to create a student (table etudiant) with multiples cursus (table course).

When i create a student (etudiant), I should be able to pick up for example 5 cursus (cours). By adding a dropdown list and a + button to make another dropdownlist appears.

When i look at the detail of a student, i should see all the curses he has choosen.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use a "middle table" (called etuCours in your diagram). This is the correct way of handling a many to many relation.

You probably don't need mulitple dynamic dropdowns to select multiple course, i would implement a multi select "drop down" which is more of a list.

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

There also many options available using jQuery if you want it to look pretty. Like http://loudev.com/

Using Razor it would be:

```
@{
    var foo = new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 1", Value = "1", Selected = true },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 2", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Foo 3", Value = "3", Selected = true }
    };
}

@Html.ListBox("foo", foo)
```

Comment: thanks for your replay,
The problem with the simple multiple select is that i've more than 80 cursus (which are going to be filter depending on the year of the student and on the department hes).
And i'm also not sure if i can add plug-in like loudev, i've to integrate my solution on an existing project.

thanks for your point of view, it helps me by introducing other possible solution and i will continue explore this way.